# Difference between optional values in swift?

Tags: swift, optional-values

What is the difference between:

```
var title:String? = "Title" //1
var title:String! = "Title" //2
var title:String = "Title" //3
```

What am I saying if I were to set title in each way and am I forced to unwrap each variable in a different way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about `?` and `!` like a box that might have a value or not. 
[image]

I recommend [this article](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/).

1. Optional box that **might have** value or **might not**, and that optional box is not unwrapped.

   ```
   var title:String? = "Title" //second and third picture
   ```

   You use unwrapped value like that:

   ```
   if let title = title {
       //do sth with title, here is the same like let title: String = "Title"
   }
   ```
2. Optional box that **might have** a value or **might not**, and that optional box is actually unwrapped. If there is a value and you access that value, that is ok (*second image*, just replace `?` with `!`), but if there is no value, then app crash (*third image*, just replace `?` with `!`)

   ```
   var title:String! = "Title"
   ```
3. That variable **have a value for sure**, and you cannot assign to this value `nil` (because it is not optional). Optional means that there is a value or there is no value (`nil`):

   ```
   var title:String = "Title" //first picture
   ```

Answer (score 2):

#### `var title:String? = "Title"`

`title` currently has a value of `Title`, but in the future it could possibly be `nil`.  I will need to unwrap it using optional binding:

```
if let unwrappedTitle = title {
   println(unwrappedTitle)
}
```

Or by forcing the unwrap with the `!` character

```
let unwrappedTitle = title!
```

The above will crash if `title` is `nil`

#### `var title:String! = "Title"`

`title` currently has a value of `"Title"`.  It could possibly be nil, but I know that it never will be when I am using it.  You don't need to unwrap this with optional binding or by forcing the unwrap with the `!` character.

Your program will crash if this value is ever accessed while `nil`, but the compiler will let you set this value to `nil`.

#### `var title:String = "Title"`

`title` currently has a value of `"Title"`.  This may change, but the variable `title` will always have some string value.  I don't need to check for `nil` with optional binding or by forcing an unwrap.  The compiler will not let you build if you try to set `title` to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var title:String? = "Title" //1 Nil Possible-Force Unwrap needed-Nil checking when use
var title1:String! = "Title"//2 Nil Possible-Force Unwrap not needed-Nil cheking when Use
var title2:String = "Title" //3 Nil Not possible as its initailize when declared-No force unwrap needed-No Nil Cheking is needed.
```